# Not able to convert objective-c code to swift 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode, utf-8, swift4, nsdata

Can anyone please help me convert this objective-c function to swift4?
I have tried Swiftify but it is giving wrong output. Also I have tried with string to data conversion but output is wrong.

```
- (NSData *)stringToData{
if (!HCKBluetoothValidStr(self)) {
    return nil;
}
if (!(self.length % 2 == 0)) {
    return nil;
}
Byte bytes[255] = {0};
NSInteger count = 0;
for (int i =0; i < self.length; i+=2) {

    NSString *strByte = [self substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i,2)];
    NSLog(@"strbyte is: %@ \n\n",strByte);
    unsigned long red = strtoul([strByte UTF8String],0,16);
    Byte b =  (Byte) ((0xff & red) );//( Byte) 0xff&iByte;
    bytes[i/2+0] = b;
    count ++;
}
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:count];
return data;
```

}

for same function input string is:

```
NSString *commandStr = @"1702030a0a";
```

and output from function in NSData format is:

```
<1702030a 0a>
```

## EDIT 1:

I have tried to convert it to swift, but strString.utf8CString giving error as "Cannot convert value of type 'ContiguousArray' (aka 'ContiguousArray') to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer!'"

```
func stringToData(stringVal: NSString) -> NSData {
    var bytes: [UInt8] = [0]
    var count: Int = 0
    var i = 0
    for index in stride(from: 0, to: stringVal.length , by: 2) {
        var strByte: NSString = stringVal.substring(with: NSMakeRange(index, 2)) as NSString
        print("strbyte is: \(strByte) \n\n")
        let strString = String(strByte)
        print(strString)
        var red: UInt8 = strtoul(strString.utf8CString, 0, 16)


        let b = UInt8((0xff & red))
        count = count+1
    }
    var data = NSData(bytes: bytes, length: count)
    return data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone please help me convert this objective-c function to swift4?

Your function takes a string of characters representing hexadecimal digits and converts each pair if characters - two hexadecimal digits, each represents 4 binary bits - and produces the represented byte value, which is 8 binary bits.

Ignore everything in your Objective-C, except the call to `HCKBluetoothValidStr` which presumably checks the input string is valid
 And which you will still wish to call, and write your own Swift code to convert a `String` to `Data`. You need to map each hexadecimal character to the integer it represents; i.e. `"3"` to `3`, `"c"` to `12` etc.; and combine them in pairs; e.g. something like `byteValue = firstDigitValue * 16 + secondDigitValue`.

If you get stuck ask a new question, show your Swift code, and someone will undoubtedly help you from there.

Comment: I have edited question and added my conversion code. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: You are trying to mimic the Objective-C – don't. You have a `String` in Swift, write your own code to process it – look at the functions available on `String`, think about getting individual characters, mapping those chars to integer values, combining those values (e.g. as shown in answer), etc. You don't need to use the C function `strtoul()`, you don't need to use `NSMakeRange()` – use Swift. (And it is better to ask new question if you are still stuck, do not keep editing this one as it started out asking how to convert Objective-C and not parse a hexadecimal string to bytes in Swift.)